# C++ instantiate an object through builder

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am recently learn about design pattern, I have read the article about builder pattern,https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/30166/builder-pattern-with-fluent-api. I have a question about the instantiation of the object. Here is the code inside the article:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Forward declaring the builder
class EmailBuilder;

class Email
{
  public:
    friend class EmailBuilder;  // the builder can access Email's privates

    static EmailBuilder make();

    string to_string() const {
        stringstream stream;
        stream << "from: " << m_from
               << "\nto: " << m_to
               << "\nsubject: " << m_subject
               << "\nbody: " << m_body;
        return stream.str();
    }

  private:
    Email() = default; // restrict construction to builder

    string m_from;
    string m_to;
    string m_subject;
    string m_body;
};

class EmailBuilder
{
  public:
    EmailBuilder& from(const string &from) {
        m_email.m_from = from;
        return *this;
    }

    EmailBuilder& to(const string &to) {
        m_email.m_to = to;
        return *this;
    }

    EmailBuilder& subject(const string &subject) {
        m_email.m_subject = subject;
        return *this;
    }

    EmailBuilder& body(const string &body) {
        m_email.m_body = body;
        return *this;
    }

    operator Email&&() {
        return std::move(m_email); // notice the move
    }

  private:
    Email m_email;
};

EmailBuilder Email::make()
{
    return EmailBuilder();
}

// Bonus example!
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const Email& email)
{
    stream << email.to_string();
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com")
                              .to("you@mail.com")
                              .subject("C++ builders")
                              .body("I like this API, don't you?");

    cout << mail << endl;
}
```

Can someone explain `Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com")`, how does it works?

Comment: "_Can someone explain `Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com")`, how does it works?_" What, about it, is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the statement:

```
Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com");
```

In the first part, we call `Email::make()`, this returns a new temporary `EmailBuilder`. This object is responsible for filling an `Email`, which is a private member of it. We can fill the internals of `Email` since it is a `friend` class (which should be used **with caution**!! Don't abuse it!).

Now, we call the member method `from`, which fills the `m_form` member of the `Email`, and **returns** `EmailBuilder`. This is for allowing using concatenated usage of the functions of `EmailBuilder`, for example:

```
Email mail = Email::make().from("me@mail.com").to("other@mail.com");
```

Is a **valid** command, that fills both the from and to fields (and it is common to see such usages).

Finally, we have the `operator Email&&()`. This is the ***casting operator*** of `EmailBuilder` to a r-value reference `Email`. This moves the internal `Email` that we created to the outside, allowing *grabbing* the internals of `Email` into the `Email mail`. And this is where the "*magic*" of transforming this builder to the actual mail occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`Email::make()` returns a new instance of `Email` which is modified (in fact its member `m_email`) by `from()` which returns the reference of the instance allowing it to be modified again by `to()` etc and finally the operator defining the conversion allows to get the `Email`. The instance of `EmailBuilder` is a temporary variable. Note `friend class EmailBuilder` allows `EmailBuilder` to access/modify private fields of `Email`

If `to()` etc does not return the reference to the instance you cannot pipe the modifications and have to save the instance of `EmailBuilder` first to later apply `from()` etc on it

It is the same in `cout << mail << endl;`, you can pipe the `<<`  because the `operator <<` returns the instance of the `std::ostream`, but that time there is no temporary variable.